# Simple Pie Chart not working in custom module. Do you see any errors in my code?

Tags: charts

I am running Drupal 9 in Lando.  I have enabled the Charts and Highcharts modules and installed the Highcharts JS library with composer. I wrote a simple module to display a Pie Chart but the chart won't display.  My code is below.  Do you see any glaring errors or ways I can debug this? I ported this from an example that runs fine in D7 in DevDesktop.
The info yaml file.

```yaml
name: My Test Chart
description: This is an example use of the Charts module.
package: Custom
type: module
core_version_requirement: ^9
dependencies:
  - chart
```

The router yaml file.

```yaml
example_chart:
  path: 'mychart-example'
  defaults:
    _title: 'My Example Chart'
    _controller: '\Drupal\mychart\Controller\MyChartController::example_page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

The library yaml file.

```yaml
highcharts:
  js:
    libraries/highcharts/highcharts.js: {  }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

The Controller.

```php
namespace Drupal\mychart\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MyChartController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * @return array
   */
  function example_page() {
    $chart = array(
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array('mychart/highcharts'),
      ),
      '#type' => 'chart',
      '#chart_type' => 'pie',
      '#chart_library' => 'highcharts',
      '#title' => t('Simple Pie Chart'),
    );
    $chart['pie_data'] = array(
      '#type' => 'chart_data',
      '#title' => t('Gender'),
      '#data' => array(array('Male', 10), array('Female', 20)),
    );
    return  $chart;
  }
}
```

Comment: What documentation are you following to create your render array? Are there any js errors in console? What do you see for markup in the page's rendered html?

Comment: Is the highcharts rendering process the exact same in Drupal 9 as it was Drupal 7?

Comment: No JS errors in the console.  Nothing in the logs.  Nothing when I view source.  But the title, Simple Pie Chart, is printed as an H1 so it is rendering something.  Just no chart.  The docs I am following are for D7 but I don't see anything different for D9.  One clue, when I view source I don't see any JS code for Highcharts.  Does my library file look OK?  I see highcharts.js under libraries/highcharts but I think it is not being found or used.  Not sure how to debug this.

Comment: I tried installing google_charts and got the same behavior.  Does anyone know if there is an update on the Charts API for Drupal 9?  I am following these examples for D7; https://www.drupal.org/node/2434061.

Comment: I think the `path:` always needs to start with a slash: `path: '/mychart-example'`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was upgrading the Charts module to version 5.0.x.  Now my simple pie chart works!